# Search and replace not working in sed for string containing space and special character

Tags: string, ubuntu, sed, replace, escaping

I want to prefix the line containing the string `echo '"xxx.yyy"` with `"# "` (hash+space) in `file.txt` using `sed` in Linux.

Output should look like this:

```
# echo '"xxx.yyy"
```

I tried this:

```
find file.txt -type f -exec sed -i 's|"echo '"xxx.yyy""|"# echo '"xxx.yyy""|g' {} \;
```

But I am getting the error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 23: unterminated `s' command
```

Should I escape any character here?
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Before using `sed -i` test without `-i` until the command is working. When you make an error in the `sed` command, you don't want the existing files changed.
And test with only one file (perhaps the file `file.txt` is found in 20 different directories)

Comment: Are you sure the command is `echo '"xxx.yyy"`. It has one single and two double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will show the `sed` commands without `-i`. Add `-i` when it works like you want.
When you are not sure how much quotes you have, you can try

```
sed 's/echo [^[:alnum:]]*xxx.yyy[^[:alnum:]]/# &/' file.txt
```

or when you are already happy when a line has both `echo` and `xxx.yyy`:

```
sed 's/echo.*xxx.yyy/# &/' file.txt
```

In both commands, the `&` stands for the part that is matched.

Answer (score 1):

Your single quotes in the search and replacement are causing the error that the `s` option is unterminated as `sed` does not see the complete command.

To fix it, you can try this `sed`

```
sed -i 's|"echo '"'"'"xxx.yyy"|"# echo '"'"'"xxx.yyy""|g' file.txt
```

Comment: This shows how to change the command so it's no longer a syntax error, but the actual input does not seem to be wrapped in literal double quotes, so the script will find no strings to replace, and thus needlessly rewrite the file without any changes.